# Internal functioning of Html helpers in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I Just want to know how asp.net mvc engine generates html coresponding to the htmlhelpers. For example:

```
@Html.Textbox("t1",Model.val)
```

will generate html as

```
<input type="text" value="Model value"/>
```

I just want to know how this html generated internally.

Comment: The best way to find such things is to dive into sources. Check it out: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com

Comment: Html helpers are extension methods which return MvcHtmlString(string kind of). e.g  @Html.Textbox return string something like <input name="" type="text"/> and write it into html document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the source code for it on codeplex:

```
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1026:DefaultParametersShouldNotBeUsed", Justification = "The purpose of these helpers is to use default parameters to simplify common usage.")]
        public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value = null, string cssClass = null, string dir = null, bool disabled = false, string id = null, string lang = null, int? maxLength = null, bool readOnly = false, int? size = null, string style = null, int? tabIndex = null, string title = null)
        {
            return htmlHelper.TextBox(
                name,
                value,
                InputAttributes(cssClass, dir, disabled, id, lang, maxLength, readOnly, size, style, tabIndex, title));
        }
```

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/Html/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs